# how to get json response form parse.com using query.find(); using javascript in web app?

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform

i'm using parse.com for the first time and searching for the way to get json response using javascript api. actually, i'm using handlebars as template engine and trying to get json response form parse.com so i can easily pass it to handlebars template. currently, i'm getting object response which needs to do like result.get("title"). i searched the parse.com javascript guide and documentation but couldn't find the way to do this. i'm want to get all the feeds records from parse.com class as json. is there any way to do this any soution??

here's handlebars template script::

```
<script id="post-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each feeds}}
        <div class="post" style="padding-top: 5px; width: 307px; margin: 0 auto;" >
            <div style="background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5); text-align: left;">
                <img src="{{post-img}}" alt="image"/>
                <p>{{post-mes}}</p>
                <p style="position: relative;">
                    <img src="{{post-by-img}}" alt="image" /><label>  By @{{post-by}}</label>
                    <label class="ago" style="vertical-align: top; position: absolute; right: 10px; top: 18px; height: 20px;">{{post-dt}}</label>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="javascript: alert('Like')" class="button like" >Like</a>
                <a href="javascript: alert('Comment')" class="button comment" >Comment</a>
                <a href="javascript: alert('Share')" class="button share" >Share</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
    </script>
```

sample json i'm using to test template::

```
feeds:[
    {
    'post-img': 'assets/images/photo1.png',
    'post-mes': 'Before the party, with @Marie',
    'post-by':  'Naza',
    'post-by-img':'assets/images/by.jpg',
    'post-dt':  '5 min'
    },
    {
    'post-img': 'assets/images/photo1.png',
    'post-mes': 'Before the party, with @Marie',
    'post-by':  'Naza',
    'post-by-img':'assets/images/by.jpg',
    'post-dt':  '10 min'
    },
    {
    'post-img': 'assets/images/photo1.png',
    'post-mes': 'Before the party, with @Marie',
    'post-by':  'Naza',
    'post-by-img':'assets/images/by.jpg',
    'post-dt':  '15 min'
    }
]
```

and parse.com script::

```
var feedsObject = Parse.Object.extend("feeds");
var query = new Parse.Query(feedsObject);

        query.find({ ... });
```

i like to get it as following::

```
query.find({
    success: function(feeds){
        //load home page template
        var source = $('#post-template').html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var html = template(feeds);  // here's example with some details [link](http://screencast.com/t/XvPFuafRuIW)
        $('#home .content').append(html);

    },
    error: function(object, error){
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: @asgoth
here's handlebars template script: [link](http://screencast.com/t/lBYE9JCTi) and the demo json object using with it: [link](http://screencast.com/t/yyqYeEHlJo). now i'm trying to get same json response from parse.com. and here is my parse script: [link](http://screencast.com/t/XvPFuafRuIW) (_i know the script is wrong but it's example how i want the response to be (as a json so i can pass the as it is like in screenshot)_). currently, there is multiple datas and i have to do query.count and something like feeds[i].get("feed_des") etc.

Comment: it might be easier if you just copy/paste the snippets in your question. Makes it easier for SO users to follow.

Comment: @asgoth - question updated with snippets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used Parse.com (in fact, didnt know it existed). But in the example [here](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries), it returns an array of `Parse.Object` instances.

`Parse.Object` has a function [toJSON()](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#toJSON). This should do it.

So in your case:

```
query.find({
    success: function(feeds){
        var jsonArray = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < feeds.length; i++) {
           jsonArray.push(feeds[i].toJSON());
        } 

        //load home page template
        var source = $('#post-template').html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var html = template(jsonArray);  // here's example with some details [link](http://screencast.com/t/XvPFuafRuIW)
        $('#home .content').append(html);

    },
    error: function(object, error){
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: There really should be a way skip iterating through the array and just  call a toJSON on the actual array returned.